# What is a ROS package?

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Information on ROS packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9036/what-is-a-ros-package?/) by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8372 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AbuIbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/6791/abuibra/) on 2014-03-19**:
good "karma-question"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Software in ROS is organized in packages. A package might contain ROS nodes, a ROS-independent library, a dataset, configuration files, a third-party piece of software, or anything else that logically constitutes a useful module. The goal of these packages it to provide this useful functionality in an easy-to-consume manner so that software can be easily reused. In general, ROS packages follow a "Goldilocks" principle: enough functionality to be useful, but not too much that the package is heavyweight and difficult to use from other software.

See http://www.ros.org/wiki/Packages for more details.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12